# Which kinds of herbs can be grown in flower pots?

Tags: herbs, growth

I don't have a terrace garden, so I was wondering which kind of ***herbs***
can be grown in ***"flower pots"***?

My balcony gets abundant sunlight in summers and zero sunlight in winters.

The herbs I wish to plant are:

- Fenugreek
- Coriander
- Green chilies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a simple question which might have a simple answer. It doesn't, not really. First, let me say that it's possible to grow almost anything in pots - what eventually constricts growth on most large plants will be not enough root room, so a large tree won't get too large, for instance, and may become stunted.

Generally speaking, depending which herbs you want to grow, use containers with a depth of 8-12 inches, no less. The more root room you give for them, the better they will do, and on a hot balcony, you won't have to be watering 3 times a day, as you would in small pots. Some herbs, like parsley, do better in wider containers 8 inches deep - you need a bigger area on top of the container to grow enough to be useful for cooking, so something like an 8 inch deep trough or window box is good for something like that.

Your climate and micro climate are important considerations when choosing which herbs you might grow, rather more important than the question of containers. You may gather from this answer that, in fact, it depends which herbs you want to grow, so I suggest you decide which ones you want, and then check out whether they'll grow 1) in your area and 2) what size pots you might need to use.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Fenugreek (Trigonella) is an annual plant, can be grown from seed in spring, will reach about 75 cm in a good sized pot.
Coriander (Coriandrum sativum) is another annual, grown from seed in spring. Needs a deepish pot to reach its full size, keep well watered. Let flower if you want to collect seeds for food use.
Chili peppers (Capsicum) count as a vegetable rather than a herb - again, an annual, needs a good sized pot too (all should be around 20cm deep).

Comment: @Darian and Bamboo, have edited the question. Added the herbs.

Comment: thanks for the update. what about lemon? Is that a herb?

Comment: Lemon THYME is a herb, but Lemon as in Lemon the citrus fruit is not a herb, its a tree.

Answer (score 2):

Any herb can grow in a flower pot but if i had to suggest my personal favorite. I would say that the rosemary plant would be the best plant for the setting you described. They can grow in  both sunny and shaded areas. They are similar to the evergreen trees with the needlelike leaves which is designs by nature to keep it protected through winter. Because they are woody plants they take longer to grow making it great for a container. Plus they smell great.